# Can I use Event Hub as a backplane for SignalR

Tags: signalr, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, signalr-backplane

Now I'm using service bus topic as a backplane for signalr. But event hub is much cheaper than topics. Therefore, I want use Event Hub as a backplane for SignalR.
Can I do this now or in near feature ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381164/signalr-high-frequency-scaling-out-with-windowsazure-eventhub/30418191 for more detail once you've decided "I can write code."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a real answer, but it looks like to me. I am not sure whether Event Hub is suitable for your goal, but assuming you verified and it is, then you can write your own backplane supporting it. For exercise I wrote one which was using SignalR itself (doh) as a backplane system and it was not damn difficult. You can take inspiration from the [source code of the one for Service Bus](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus) and roll out your own. In particular you'll have to put most of your logic when implementing your version of a [`ScaleoutMessageBus`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus/ServiceBusMessageBus.cs)-derived class.